# Issue with cocoapods and Xcode 13 whe publishing an App

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, assets

I've got a project made by modules and each module is a cocoapods library that loads each section of the App.

This application was made 1 and a half years ago and it has been maintained and it's been working without problems but now i just had to do an small change (the first change that i did to this app using Xcode 13) and the problem is that when i compile in my iPhone, iPad, or any simulator, everything works perfectly, but when i send the app to TestFlight, the colors and the images contained inside the modules (cocoapods libraries) doesn't appear.
The views and the languages are working but not the colors and the images (that colors and the images of each module are inside an xcassets included in the module itself).

This is the podspec of my modules:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  
  s.name             = 'ModuleName'
  s.version          = '1.2.7'
  s.summary          = 'This is an awesome description.'
  s.description      = 'Another awesome description here.'
  s.homepage         = 'site.com'
  s.license          = { :type => 'Copyright (c)', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'My name' => 'mymail@mycompany.com' }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/devinet_es'
  s.platform         = :ios, '15.0'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  s.swift_versions   = ['4.0', '4.1', '4.2', '5.0', '5.1', '5.2']
  s.source           = { :git => 'repoGitAddr', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.frameworks       = 'UIKit'
  s.source_files     = 'ModuleName/Classes/**/*'
  s.exclude_files    = 'ModuleName/**/*.plist'
  s.resource_bundles = { 'ModuleName' => ['ModuleName/Assets/**/*.{strings,xib,xcassets,storyboard,imageset,colorset}'] }
  
  s.dependency 'Tags', '~>0.3.1'
  s.dependency 'Klendario', '~>1.0.1'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '~>5.0.1'
  s.dependency 'PopupDialog', '~>1.1.1'
  s.dependency 'CryptoSwift', '~>1.4.2'
  s.dependency 'DVNTAlertManager', '~>1.1.15'
  s.dependency 'DVNTAlamofireWrapper', '~>2.4.0'
end
```

Does anyone have any idea of why it's working when i test the app on my devices (no matter if i test it in release or development mode) but not when i upload the code to TestFlight.

**NOTE:** I'm using cocoapods 1.11.2 and i already tried to change the optimization levels in the 'build settings' to 'none' and i also tried to compile using Xcode 13.1 RC (i thought it could be some kind of Xcode 13.0 bug)

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the pod and resource bundle being the same causes issue. Try putting a unique name for the resource bundle

Comment: This is not a safe solution, For example If the pod contains some views that Initialized from a xib you should search the xib in 1 bundle and the .swift file in another one. otherwise the app will crash.

Comment: You were right, i changed the name of the resource bundle and now it's compiling correctly for production and all my assets are working. I don't know why it was working until this new version of xcode but this trick is working!

Comment: Thank you, we had this issue for over a week, this solved it!